# spresense Ethernet shield2 W5500　で通信できません

Tags: spresense

スケッチ例のEthrenet2 WebServerを使っていますが、ARPにすら乗ってきません（Macアドレスは入れています）。
Ethernetのリンクは点灯します。ACTは定期的に点灯。
シリアルモニタではserver is at 255.255.255.255 となってしまいます。

Answer (score 1):

Arduino Ethernet Shield 2 には、ICSPコネクタがついているので、SPRESENSE の拡張ボードに接続しようとしても物理的な干渉があるので、うまく接続できないように思うのですが...

仮にできたとしても、SPRESENSEとEthernet Shield 2 が通信するための SPI は ICSP コネクタ側にあるので、そのまま載せても通信ができないと思います。SPRESENSE 拡張ボードの SPI を、Ethernet Shield 2 の ICSPコネクタへワイヤで接続すれば動くと思います。ピン配は以下の回路図で確認できます。

https://www.arduino.cc/en/uploads/Main/arduino-Ethernet-Shield2-V2-sch.pdf